# ploting two scattered graph in one graph

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plot

I have two numpy array and want to plot them in the same graph

My current code is like this below

```
X1 # numpy array
X2 # numpy array

X1Df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y'])
k = 0
for i in X1:                        # copy second numpy to DataFrome
    temp = pd.DataFrame({'x' : i[0],
                         'y' : i[1]},index=[k])
    k = k + 1
    X1Df = pd.concat([X1Df,temp])

X1Df.plot(kind='scatter',x = 'x',y='y')



X2Df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y'])
k = 0
for i in X2: ## Copy second numpy to DataFrame
    temp = pd.DataFrame({'x' : i[0],
                         'y' : i[1]},
                        index=[k])
    k = k + 1
    X2Df = pd.concat([X2Df,temp])

X2Df.plot(kind='scatter',x = 'x',y='y')

#########
plt.show()
```

But it makea two graphs separately and I guess my code to copy from numpy to dataframe is ackward...

is ther any better solution??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use axes handle and `ax` paramater in `df.plot`:

```
X1 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
X2 = np.array([[2,3],[6,7]])

X1Df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y'])
k = 0
for i in X1:                        # copy second numpy to DataFrome
    temp = pd.DataFrame({'x' : i[0],
                         'y' : i[1]},index=[k])
    k = k + 1
    X1Df = pd.concat([X1Df,temp])

ax = X1Df.plot(kind='scatter',x = 'x',y='y')



X2Df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y'])
k = 0
for i in X2: ## Copy second numpy to DataFrame
    temp = pd.DataFrame({'x' : i[0],
                         'y' : i[1]},
                        index=[k])
    k = k + 1
    X2Df = pd.concat([X2Df,temp])

X2Df.plot(kind='scatter',x = 'x',y='y', ax=ax)

#########
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! that's what I needed